# Creating a DTM from a LiDAR map in QGIS 3.22.7

Tags: qgis-processing

I'd like to create a DTM from a LiDAR map in QGIS 3.22.7
I looked at a [tutorial](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/basic_lidar.html?highlight=digital%20terrain%20model) that explains how to do it, but it seems as if the instructions there refer to a different version of QGIS because I can't find where to include the LAStools library as specified in the instructions.
For example, there it is said that

> Go to Processing ► Options and configuration.

> In the Processing options dialog, go to Providers and then to **Tools for LiDAR data**

> Check Activate

But there is no 'Tools for LiDAR data' item to be activated. Nor there is any possibility there to add one and link it to the downloaded LAStools library
[image]

So there must be a different way to do it.
How?

Comment: Did you install the plugin? Go to `Plugins>Manage and install plugins>` .  Search for LAStools and install. Then check you options and configurations menu again.

Comment: No it didn't occur to me. I was just trying to follow the instructions ... and I am new to QGIS. But thanks now I could installi it!